# JQuery change variable / cost after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hey I'm trying to create a incremental game and am stuck.
You press one button and get a currency which is called "Evos". With these "Evos" you can buy a storyteller who will start to generate "Evos" on his own.

this is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
"use strict";
var evoAmount = 0;

var storytellerAmount = 0;

var evoIncrement = 1;

var storyteller = {
    Amount: 0,
    Cost: 10,
    Increment: 1
};

var tick = 1000;




var runstoryteller = setInterval(function () {
    evoAmount = evoAmount + (storyteller.Increment * storyteller.Amount);
    updateValues();
}, tick);

function updateValues(){
     $('#evoAmount').html(evoAmount);
     $('#storytellerAmount').html(storyteller.Amount);
}


/* Buy storytellers */
$('#storytellerBuy').click(function () {
    if (evoAmount >= storyteller.Cost) {
        evoAmount = evoAmount - storyteller.Cost;
        storyteller.Amount++;
  storyteller.Cost = (storyteller.Cost / 100) * 20;
        updateValues();
    }
});





$('#click').click(function(){
 evoAmount = evoAmount + evoIncrement;
 document.getElementById("evoAmount").innerHTML = evoAmount;
  
});












});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://bootswatch.com/slate/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Evo-Clicker v1.0.0</title>
</head>

<body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="js/click.js"></script>

<div class="main"> 
<button id="click" class="btn btn-default">Click</button>
<span id="evoAmount">0</span> EVOs <br><br>
<button id="storytellerBuy" class="btn btn-danger">Buy Storyteller</button><span id ="storytellerAmount">0</span> Storytellers

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Basically i can buy the first storyteller for 10 Evos. But i want to increase the cost with each bought storyteller by 20%. But if i change the code it either goes into negative "Evos" or in this example you only have to pay once and then buy storytellers for free.

```
/* Buy storytellers */
$('#storytellerBuy').click(function () {
    if (evoAmount >= storyteller.Cost) {
        evoAmount = evoAmount - storyteller.Cost;
        storyteller.Amount++;
        updateValues();
    }
});
```

This works but the stays the same. (Which i want to increase by 20% each time)

Comment: Are you using this piece of code to increase the cost? storyteller.Cost = (storyteller.Cost / 100) * 20;
If so, this assigns the cost as 20% of the current cost. I think you need storyteller.Cost = storyteller.Cost  + (storyteller.Cost*0.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace the calculation of cost

this is the right one
storyteller.Cost = (storyteller.Cost * 1.2);

Comment: Thanks :) This fixed it but do you have a idea why i sometimes get values like "6.000000000004 Evos" ?

Comment: If you want an integer number you have to round the result:
' storyteller.Cost = Math.round(storyteller.Cost * 1.2);'